# what are down votes for?

Tags: support

Are you supposed to down vote if you don't personally like the question, or are you supposed to down vote if the question is offensive/makes-no-sense or is just really off on any point the asker is trying to make?

Comment: Empirical information tells me that down votes are only for my questions ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [help center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)

> Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information. The more that people vote on a post, the more certain future visitors can be of the quality of information contained within that post – not to mention that upvotes are a great way to thank the author of a good post for the time and effort put into writing it!

That's basically all the guidance you're given. If it's useful, vote it up, if it's not, vote it down.

Comment: The only thing I would add to this is a note about [not voting based on doctrinal positions that you (dis)agree with](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/982/75) but on answer quality and suitability.

Comment: @Caleb On principle you're exactly right.  In practice, the community doesn't always adhere to that.

Comment: @TheFreemason Of course it doesn't. But that is no excuse for not taking the chance to educate on proper voting. All we have to do is teach/train enough percentage of site users and the bad vote reasons will get buried in the noise. That's how the system works.

Comment: Agreed, you are describing the way it should be and I commend you on your effort to teach.